# What's the difference between や　and やら?

Tags: grammar

I know these both are used a delimiters when things are listed in a way implying the list is not necessarily limited to the things explicitly mentioned, but when would one be used over the other?

Comment: http://jisho.org/search/%E3%82%84%E3%82%89 As it says, semantic difference between the conjunctive particle usage and や is uncertainty. In addition, やら has usages as an adverbial particle and a sentence ending particle as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am going to take your question literally and discuss only the difference between 「や」 and 「やら」 as **parallel markers** and ***not*** as other types of particles.

> 「や」 is used to juxtapose ***nouns*** and ***nominalized words*** only.
>
> 「やら」 is used to juxtapose not only nouns but also adjectives and verbs.

**For that very reason, the two words are not always interchangeable**.

Examples:

> Nouns:

〇「日本{にほん}に行{い}ったら、スシ**や**たこやき**や**すきやきなどを食{た}べてみたい。」

〇「日本に行ったら、スシ**やら**たこやき**やら**すきやきなどを食べてみたい。」

> Adjectives:

✖「もうすぐ卒業{そつぎょう}。うれしい**や**かなしい**や**、複雑{ふくざつ}な気持{きも}ちです。」

〇「もうすぐ卒業。うれしい**やら**かなしい**やら**、複雑な気持ちです。」

> Verbs:

✖「プールに行く**や**、ゲームをする**や**で、忙{いそが}しい夏休{なつやす}みだった。」

〇「プールに行く**やら**、ゲームをする**やら**で、忙しい夏休みだった。」